# TexBox, Uri & Classes

Tags: c#, file, textbox, uri, config

I use [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) to create a Config file generator, in other C# Form project I add the `ini` Class of the Config file generator project, create 2 not visible `textboxes` and use the `ReadValue` of the Config generator project to read the urls created by the Config file gen previously; This project uses a Uri to download a file and I want that Uri to be the not visible textbox text (That is a url in the config file) but when I do

```
IniFile ini = new IniFile("C:\\Config.ini");
TextBox1.Text= ini.IniReadValue("Config","Patch URL");
```

to write the Uri (`private Uri PatchLocation = new Uri(TextBox1.Text);`)
Says **"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Downloader.Form1.TextBox1'"**.
What I need to do for make the Uri be the TextBox text then?
Hope someone could help me, because I really need to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `private Uri PatchLocation = new Uri(TextBox1.Text);` try

```
private Uri PatchLocation
{
    get
    {
        return new Uri(TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Basically, the code you have currently is saying "when I initialize this Form1 object, set PatchLocation to what I get from Textbox1" which isn't what you want - and the compiler won't let you do it anyway.

The code I've given is a property, which means it won't read the contents of Textbox1 *until you try to read* `PatchLocation`. Every time you try to read `PathLocation`, it will parse the value out from `TextBox1.Text`. It will throw an exception if that value isn't a valid URI at the time.

**Edit**: Actually, having fully read your question, you'd be much better off at least removing the hidden textbox and using

```
private Uri PatchLocation
{
    get
    {
        IniFile ini = new IniFile("C:\\Config.ini");
        return ini.IniReadValue("Config","Patch URL");
    }
}
```

unless you have a *really* compelling reason to be using a hidden textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include required namespace for IniFile class?

```
using Ini;
```

Btw this line looks wrong `new Uri("TextBox1.Text")`. Change to `new Uri(TextBox1.Text)`

Comment: Yes, I include the Ini class, and thanks for the "", but in my form is already without them.